# В ответе невозможно оформить частичную html разметку в виде кода

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, правки, редактор

В данном ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527904/199733 редактор не дал оформить html код, собственно как код, пришлось оформлять его как цитату.

Comment: для подсветки кода в списках нужно 8 пробелов вместо 4. я исправил сообщение.

Comment: @PashaPash о как, спасибо. Напишите тогда Ваш комментарий в ответ.